# How to store data from a ListModel?

Tags: vala, storage

Is there some sort of standard or commonly-used way to store data in elementary apps? I currently have a bunch of GObjects contained in a ListModel and would like to persist that to the disk and reload it when the app opens again. The Settings object doesn't seem like quite the right place for it as it's an unbounded chunk of text data from user input. Should I just stuff it in a leveldb instance or something? Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I used a json array to save some data for an application I'm building. The data is saved in a file in the user's .config folder. Take a look at the [writeServers method](https://github.com/popvladaurel/torrential-remote/blob/75d092cc2d7e1883f77115ffd9bc9cd40a14b748/src/Server/Controller.vala#L95).

If you go over the entire [file](https://github.com/popvladaurel/torrential-remote/blob/75d092cc2d7e1883f77115ffd9bc9cd40a14b748/src/Server/Controller.vala#L1), you'll see that it first verifies that the file exists, and creates it if it does not.

[image]